# Retrieve specific record from database in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please look at my sample code below:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Key]
    public int LoginId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Key]
    public int RegisterId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

}
```

There are many records in the cart table added by many users.
But i want to show the own record of a user from the cart table if he is logged in..how can I do this??

Comment: Can you explain why you have two nearly identical tables (LoginModel and RegisterModel) ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a foreign-key property to your Cart class:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [Key]
    public int LoginId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public string CartId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public virtual UserModel User { get; set; } // <-- added
}
```

Then you can use LINQ to query the Cart-items for a specific user:

```
var cartItems = dbContext.Cart.Where(a => a.User == loggedInUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from a in db.Pages
            where a.title.Contains(myTitle)
            select a;
var item=query.FirstOrDefault();
if(item!=null)
   return View(item);
else
   return View("NotFound");
```